# I saw a man in the room

Tags: attachment-ambiguity

1. I saw a man in the room.
2. I saw the man in the room.

---

1a. I saw a man who was in the room.
There were five people in the room, for example. I saw one man who was in the room. In this case, 'in the room' can modify 'a man'.

1b. In the room, I saw a man. In this case 'in the room' modifies 'saw' in Sentence 1. So Sentence 1 also has structural ambiguity, doesn't it?

Comment: The way you've formatted your question is very confusing. What role does sentence *2* play? You've listed it, but you only *ask* about *1a* and *1b*. (Which you *don't* list.) Does sentence *2* have any purpose? Why didn't you just list *1a* and *1b*?

Answer (score 0):

In (1), "in the room" is an adverbial adjunct of place.

In (2), "in the room" can be:

2a. an adverbial adjunct of place if it can be placed at the beginning of the sentence without any change of meaning:

- In the room, I saw the man.

2b. a postmodifier of the noun phrase "the man" if the meaning is:

- I saw the man who was in the room.